# How to use advanced where clauses and operators using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How would I produce a query that displays user_id 1 whos a member of the club and  subjects that are either football or tennis.

```
id|user_id|member|subject
1 | 1     |Yes   |football
2 | 1     |Yes   |NULL
3 | 2     |Yes   |football
4 | 3     |Yes   |tennis
5 | 1     |No    |tennis
6 | 1     |Yes   |tennis
```

So basically I would like the resulting rows to be:

```
id|user_id|member|subject
1 | 1     |Yes   |football
6 | 1     |Yes   |tennis
```

Comment: Can we see whatever code you have for this so far? It often helps to understand the question, as well as to encourage posters from trying to get as far as they can on their own.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')->
    where('user_id','=','1')->
    where('subject','!=','Null')->
    distinct()->
    get();
```

Comment: sorry @user4621032 and halfer and thank you for your answers but I phrased the question wrong I've reposted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630694/how-to-use-advanced-where-clause-while-using-or-operators