# How to use advanced where clause while using OR operators

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How would I produce a query that displays user_id 1 whos a member of the club and subjects that are either football or tennis or cricket.

```
id|user_id|member|football|tennis|cricket
1 | 1     |Yes   | 1      | NULL | NULL
2 | 1     |Yes   | NULL   | NULL | NULL
3 | 2     |Yes   | NULL   | 1    | NULL
4 | 3     |Yes   | 1      | 1    | NULL
5 | 1     |No    | NULL   | 1    | NULL
6 | 1     |Yes   | NULL   | 1    | 1
```

So basically I would like the resulting rows to be:

```
id|user_id|member|football|tennis|cricket
1 | 1     |Yes   | 1      | NULL | NULL
6 | 1     |Yes   | NULL   | 1    | 1
```

So far I have this:

```
$user = Model::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('cricket', 1)
          ->orWhere('tennis', 1);
          ->orWhere('football', 1);
        })->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', 1)
          ->Where('member', '=', 'Yes');
     });
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user_id = 1 AND member = 'yes' AND (football = 1 OR tennis = 1 OR cricket = 1) Basically you need to place the OR statements in parentheses. But i dont know what SQL object "Model" you are using. Also, I think the 'Yes' needs to be quoted.

Comment: thanks @Jeffrey im using the laravel fw so i was hoping for an eloquent solution. Yes you're right 'Yes' should be quoted

Comment: @Billy I've added an eloquent solution -- is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, you've joined the ranks of [Advanced Where](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses) users -- welcome!

```
$user = Model::
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->where('member', 'Yes')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query
            ->where('cricket', 1)
            ->orWhere('tennis', 1);
            ->orWhere('football', 1);
    })
    ->select(['id', 'user_id', 'member', 'football', 'tennis', 'cricket'])
    ->get()
;
```